# postgresql migration without creating a dump

Tags: database, postgresql, database-migration

In a server with a single postgres database, is it possible to migrate the whole database  onto a different server (running the same OS, etc) **without** going through the usual time-consuming way of dumping and importing (pg_dump)?

After all, everything must still be in the filesystem?

Assumptions are the postgres service is not running, and the servers are running Ubuntu.

Comment: you can `file copy` the full pg `data` folder to your server

Comment: `FATAL:  incorrect checksum in control file` :( 64-32bit architecture issues?

Comment: Yep, the 5 minute version [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Binary_Replication_Tutorial) worked. Simply copying `/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main` actually worked for 32-bit to 32-bit machines. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, if you want, you can use pg_basebackup which will connect over the network connection and request a copy of all files.  This is preferable where the architecture, OS, etc. is not changing.  For more complex cases, see [barman](http://www.pgbarman.org) which will manage this process for you.